# How can I use ng-if to display a button based on the current user?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, angular-ng-if

I am create a user profile and would like to show an edit button that only displays for the profile's owner. I am attempting to use ng-if so that the edit capabilities are removed from the DOM.

How can I use ng-if to display a button based on the current user?

In my view:

```
<button ng-if="editProfile()">EDIT</button>
```

In my controller:

```
$scope.editProfile = function (canedit) {
  var canedit = false;
  for (var i=0;i<$scope.users.length;i++) {
    if ($scope.users[i].id===$scope.currentUser.id) {
      canedit = true;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's there is fine, the problem is you're missing the `return`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function needs to return `true` or `false`

```
<button ng-if="editProfile()">EDIT</button>


$scope.editProfile = function () {
  for (var i=0;i<$scope.users.length;i++) {
    if ($scope.users[i].id===$scope.currentUser.id) {
      return true
     }
  }
  return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning nothing from your function.

You can make it this way

```
<button ng-if="canEdit()">EDIT</button>
```

and in your controller

```
$scope.canEdit = function () {
    return $scope.users.find(u=>u.id === $scope.currentUser.id) ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
return canedit;
```

below the for closing bracket

Answer (score 0):

As everyone mentioned, the function wasn't returning true or false. After adding the return I discovered that the for statement was extraneous and I just needed a simple check. This code is working correctly:

```
$scope.editProfile = function () {
  if ($scope.user.id===$scope.currentUser.id) {
    return true
  }
   return false
 }
```